# Why is the speed of a distant object proportional to its distance from a reference object?

Tags: space-expansion, speed

Why is the linear speed of a distant object in space proportional to its distance from a reference object (Earth in this case)? How can we derive this?

If I consider a sphere with volume expansion rate of $k$ and two points at a distance of $r_2$ and $r_1$ from the center, how do I go about calculating $\text{d}(r_2 - r_1)/\text{d}t$, which would be the required velocity?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question is about the expanding universe:

If space expands (assumption: constant rate), then after a time $\Delta t$ a star in distance $x$ is now in $2x$, meaning we would measure a speed (by redshift) of $\frac{x}{\Delta t}$. Consider another star in $2x$, after the same time this star is in $4x$, so we measure a speed of $\frac{2x}{\Delta t}$, which is twice as fast.

The point is, the absolute change (and therefore speed) is proportional to the distance.